# gnuplot - regarding legend: how to set the box at middle and set the box size

Tags: gnuplot

Default positions are: top, bottom, left, right, etc - but no "middle". When I use

```
set key top
```

The legend is placed at top right, by default. How to position it at "top middle"?

Besides, when I add a frame to the legend box, can I control the width of the box? I need this because sometimes the frame cut the text in the legend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of middle, use `center`. You can find this instruction in gnuplot by using `help`

```
gnuplot> help key
 The `set key` command enables a key (or legend) describing plots on a plot. 
 [...]
 Syntax:
       set key {on|off} {default}
                     [...]
                    {left | right | center} {top | bottom | center}
```

All the other answers are also provided in this help.

Comment: how about the width of the frame?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question, there is a `center` option instead of `middle`:

```
set key top center
```

To change the width of the box, try

```
set key width 10
```

(or some other number) and see if that helps.  If that does not help, can you post a minimal code example?  You can also try

```
help set key
```

in gnuplot for more details about all the options available.